# Advanced typescript interface

Tags: typescript, интерфейс

у меня есть объект и интерфейс

```
interface Themes {
  [key:string]: {[key:string]: string} | string
}

const themes: Themes = {
    blue: {
      static: '#4687ed',
      hover: '#589bfe',
      active: '#1e4bb8',
      color: '#fff'
    },
    confirmed: '#e3f2d9'
}
```

в случае если я обращаюсь к свойству объекта ТС ругается

themes.blue.color -- color не существует в типе string

как правильно описать интерфейс?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ElementStyle {
    color?: string
    hover?: string
    active?: string
    static?: string
}

interface Themes {
    blue?: ElementStyle
    confirmed?: string
}

const themes: Themes = { }
```

---

Если сделать проверку типов более строгой использовав опцию `strictNullChecks` и использовать Type Guards, то можно получить больше гарантий в коде:

```
// Type Guard
function isString(arg: any): arg is string {
    return typeof arg === 'string'
}
```

Для строгой проверки на `null` и `undefined` в `tsconfig.json` нужно добавить:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true
    }
}
```

Проверка и пример использования:

```
const themes: Themes = {
    blue: {
        static: '#4687ed',
        hover: '#589bfe',
        active: '#1e4bb8',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    confirmed: '#e3f2d9'
}

let maybeBlue = themes.blue // => ElementStyle | undefined
if (maybeBlue) { // => ElementStyle
    console.log(maybeBlue.active || "active is not set")
}

let maybeConfirmed = themes.confirmed // => string | undefined
if (maybeConfirmed) { // => string
    console.log(maybeConfirmed.toLocaleUpperCase())
}

const key = (function () { return "blue" }()) as keyof Themes // => "blue" | "confirmed"

let selectedTheme = themes[key] // => string | ElementStyle | undefined
if (selectedTheme) { // => string | ElementStyle
    if (isString(selectedTheme)) { // => string
        console.log(selectedTheme.toLocaleLowerCase())
    } else { // => selectedTheme != string => ElementStyle
        console.log(selectedTheme.color || "color is not set" )
    }
}
```

Comment: тогда возникает проблема если я обращаюсь к свойству theme не напрямую, а например themes[props.something].color, получаю еррор, элемент неявно имеет тип any т.к. тип Themes не содержит сигнатуру индекса, кроме того, а что если у меня свойств типа blue = 100

Comment: Я проверил, транслятор TS на `themes[selectedTheme].nothing` ошибок не показывает, конечно тут будет возвращен `undefined`, потому как однозначно узнать тип объекта находящийся по `themes[key]` в момент трансляции нельзя, это высинится в момент исполнения. Лучше я решения не знаю. Кроме того, если у тебя свойств типа `blue` много, то всех их нужно перечислить, ведь это статическая информация о типах, можешь глянуть например `lib.es5.d.ts`, там полно всяких `ResolvedDateTimeFormatOptions` и т.д.

Comment: Я для себя открыл опцию strictNullChecks, после чего появился еще один вариант описать типизацию.

Comment: @4knort Я переосмыслил решение, убрал лишнее.